# Select drop down from enum not resulting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I have the following enum:

```
  enum fulfillment_status: { processing: 1, partially_fulfilled: 2, fulfilled: 3 }
```

I attempted a dropdown select with:

```
        <%= f.select :fulfillment_status, options_for_select(@order.fulfillment_status.map {|k, v| [k.humanize.capitalize, v]}) %>
```

Error: undefined method `map' for "processing":String

Tried:

```
        <%= f.select :fulfillment_status, options_for_select(@order.fulfillment_statuses.map {|k, v| [k.humanize.capitalize, v]}) %>
        <%= f.select(:fulfillment_status, @order.fulfillment_statuses.keys.map {|fs| [fs.titleize,fs]}) %>
```

Error:  undefined method `fulfillment_statuses' for #

Tried:

```
        <%= f.select :fulfillment_status, options_for_select(@order.fulfillment_statuses) %>
```

error:

undefined method `fulfillment_statuses' for #

Which is odd because doing in the console=

```
Order.fulfillment_statuses
```

will result all of the enum values.
Every way I read to do this is the same way I attempted above

Comment: What does `<%= f.select :fulfillment_status, options_for_select(Order.fulfillment_statuses.map { |label, int| [label.humanize.capitalize, int] }) %>` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting `Error: undefined method map for "processing":String` because `@order.fulfillment_status` is represented by the value of the database column. You're expecting it to be a hash, but that hash is defined on the class, not the instance.

What you want is `Order.fulfillment_statuses`

When you use `enum fulfillment_status: { processing: 1, partially_fulfilled: 2, fulfilled: 3 }` that defines a class method called `self.fulfillment_statuses` on the class you define it on, in this case `Order`. That class method isn't available as an instance method, which is what you're trying to call via `@order.fulfillment_statuses`